# Can't Update WPF ProgressBar (not the standard tight-loop issue)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to use the ProgressBar as a representation of a percent value (I have not found an alternative control that looks right).

I am trying to set the value. It is my understanding that just setting the Value property should work, and update the control when my current event handler ends and control passes back to the UI.But no matter what I set the value to, the bar stays empty.

Here is my XAML:

```
<ProgressBar Name="LevelProgress" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" />
```

and my C#:
    LevelProgress.Value = 43.0;

I have also tried:

```
LevelProgress.SetValue(ProgressBar.ValueProperty,43.0);
```

Even setting the Value property in the XAML definition does not work.

I really don't want to have to setup some big background thread thing just to set this value. Can anyone recommend a solution, or an alternative control?

Comment: Are you using a template or style that is messing with it?  If you make the XAML `<ProgressBar Name="LevelProgress" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Value="43" />` does it work?

Comment: No, that has the same result. I am using no Templating or Styling (or than what is there by default)

Comment: a couple of ideas: look at begininit(), dispatcher (especially if you are calling the updates from another thread) and in the worst case updatelayout()

Comment: Hm...I'd try to look for something that's so obvious you might have overlooked it before, e.g. is the ProgressBar you're editing the same one you're seeing?  Check by removing it completely and observing the empty space, followed by putting it back and doing something obvious like giving it a red background.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

Do you

```
InitializeComponent();
```

Before?

```
LevelProgress.Value = 43.0;
```

I put it in the Loaded event and it worked there.

And I tried

```
<ProgressBar Name="LevelProgress" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Value="43" />
```

And it works there.  Something is wrong with the progress bar.